# How to draw bounding box in same aspect ratio with dlib imglab

Tags: dlib

I use dlib for my project. Basically it detects car in video stream. I use fhog_object_detector of dlib. When do training, it's hard to draw all object with same aspect ratio with dlib imglab tool. I have to draw object in all images, and manually change the object size in created xml file. Am I doing the right way, or it has a better way to do that work? I know dlib have just release a good CNN object detector for multi scale object detection, but because my computer doesn't have a GPU, so I can't use that.
Hope some one have a problem like me, and have found a solution.

Comment: You may try [web](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/imglab) version for image labeling, if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw all the boxes as accurately around each object as you can. You want to have a well annotated dataset.  That is useful in and of itself.  Then, when you load the data for training, adjust the aspect ratios of the loaded boxes in your code before training.  That is also a good time to look for outliers like really small boxes or boxes with extreme aspect ratios as you would probably want to exclude them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is dlib have a function to adjust the aspect ratios of the loaded boxes before training? I see target-size param, is it do that?

Comment: Yes. set_aspect_ratio()

Comment: Thank you every much for a great library. It helps me a lot in my project.